# Pass variable to AngularJS directive without isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am learning AngularJS directive, and one thing I want to do is to pass some variable `$scope.message` in the parent `scope` (a `scope` of a `controller`), and I want it to be renamed to `param` inside the `directive` `alert`. I can do this with an isolated scope:

```
<div alert param="message"></div>
```

and define

```
.directive("alert", function(){
    return{
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            param: "="
        },
        link: function(scope){
            console.log(scope.param) # log the message correctly
        }
    }
})
```

But can I do this without using isolated scope? Suppose I want to add another `directive` `toast` to the `<div toast alert></div>` and utilize the same `param` (keeping the 2-way data-binding), naively I will do

```
.directive("toast", function(){
    return{
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            param: "="
        },
        link: function(scope){
            console.log(scope.param)
        }
    }
})
```

I surely will get an error `Multiple directives [alert, toast] asking for new/isolated scope on:<div...`

So in all, my question is, how to rename parent scope variable without isolated scope, and how to share variables when two `directives` are placed on a single `DOM`?

Comment: Do you want 2 directives to bind to the same parent `$scope` property?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Modify your toast directive:

```
.directive("toast", function(){
    return{
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            var param = scope.$eval(attrs.param);
            console.log(param)
        }
    }
})
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/02833tve/).

Since toast is now on the same scope as the parent would have been (if it was allowed to be isolate scope), you can simply call $eval on scope with the param attribute to get the value.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! I should take a look at `$eval()` docs then.

Comment: does the $eval() just return the value or actually provides data-binding? It appears it only return the value, but I want to make sure.

Comment: It is just the value. If you need to simulate bindings, you could use a $watch... I believe this can be overkill though as you just have to $eval again to get the most recent value (on some ngEvent for instance).